# Can I use unmodified Grafana as the visualisation component of my commercial service?

Tags: licensing, copyright, agpl-3.0

In the light of the [new AGPL Grafana license](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/04/20/grafana-loki-tempo-relicensing-to-agplv3/), can we still use **unmodifed** Grafana served as a docker image on cloud as the visualisation component of our commercial service?

My understanding so far is that it is OK to continue using Grafana, based on this [post](https://ubunlog.com/en/grafana-cambio-de-la-licencia-de-apache-2-0-a-agplv3/):

> Those who use unmodified versions Grafana on their services or post
> the change code (for example, Red Hat Openshift and Cloud Foundry)
> they will not be affected by the license change.

And even in the worst case looks like we can use the Enterprise Edition, as mentioned [here](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/04/20/qa-with-our-ceo-on-relicensing/):

> for those that don’t intend to modify the code, simply use our
> Enterprise download. This is a free-to-use, proprietary-licensed,
> compiled binary that matches the features of the AGPL version

Any thoughts/experience on Grafana AGPL is welcome.

Comment: Are you using the docker image that is provided by your cloud provider or you spinning a custom docker container with Grafana (which edition)?

Comment: Docker image provided by AWS Fargate.